# Saucelabs: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The test with session id *** has already finished, and can't receive further commands

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, saucelabs

When i execute the test cases parallely, I get a lot of "The test has already finished errors." I am sure the following are not the cause as mentioned in Common error messages link [here](https://support.saucelabs.com/entries/35517624-Test-did-not-see-a-new-command-for-90-seconds-Timing-out-).

1. driver.quit() is not the reason why the test is marked as finished, since it is not even executed when the above error came up.
2. always managed to make sure that the no of concurrent VMs running are less than the total no of VM's available for the account.
3. Internet connection is strong and stable.

Can you kindly help with this issue to determine what is wrong?

Comment: Do you see similar errors when the tests are run sequentially? What is the detailed error or exception from SauceLabs?

Comment: I do believe there is something to fix in your parallel run config

Comment: Did you ever git this fixed? I'm having the same issue

Comment: are u you calling driver.close() anywhere

Comment: You should be calling driver.close in your test teardown

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in 2014 with my NuGet package [Saucery3](http://nuget.org/packages/saucery3).  Project homepage is [here](http://sauceforge.github.io) and is open source.

The code you want is [here](https://github.com/Sauceforge/Saucery3/blob/master/Saucery3/Tests/SauceryBase.cs) and [here](https://github.com/Sauceforge/Saucery3/blob/master/UnitTests/RestAPI/TestStatus/SauceLabsStatusNotifier.cs).

In the first link look at the Cleanup() method that implements [Teardown].

In the second link is the NotifyStatus method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that parallelisation part on your side is coded correctly, it is most likely a timeouts issue.
By default, in Saucelabs test session several timeouts are used. If any timeout is reached, session will be terminated on Saucelabs side. You can find more information here https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Configuration+Options#TestConfigurationOptions-Timeouts

Please keep in mind that Javascript command executed from WebDriver is NOT considered to be a command in Saucelabs.